# Java: Does the *ability* to throw checked exceptions slow things down?

Tags: java, performance, exception

...Or must an exception *be* thrown, to impact performance?

Refer to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619429/c-sharp-to-java-where-t-new-syntax). This is something I would like to implement, if creating instances in this way will not slow things down terribly. (I have many thousands of objects to create every second, particle systems and the like. So no, it isn't premature optimisation, considering the performance impacts that exist when using checked exceptions in Java. Thank you.)

Comment: Slow things down compared to what, exactly?

Comment: Not really on modern JVMs, no.  Entering a try {} used to have some meaningful cost to it, but that's pretty much been tuned away since hotspot.  Not an answer cause I don't have time at the moment to find references, sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create tens of millions of objects per second.  For thousands I wouldn't worry about performance unless you see a problem in the profiler.  I would also worry about making the code clear and correct first and consider profiling it later.

Having exceptions in your code has next to no impact (other than making you code slightly larger)  Throwing Exceptions is expensive but you could throw thousands of exception per second and still not impact your application performance severely. (buggy code isn't a good thing all the same)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int runs = 10000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        try {
            throwsException();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took an average of %.3f micro-second per exception%n", time / runs / 1e3);
}

private static void throwsException() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Ignored");
}
```

this test throws over one million `new Exception`s per second

```
Took an average of 0.744 micro-second per exception
```

Comment: Peter, the problem here is not just construction, it's GC. I'm using object pools, but I imagine that only mitigates things. And on mobiles, to boot.

Comment: On mobile phones you have limited resources even so, thousand per second is unlikely to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try..catch blocks make negligible difference. Throwing exceptions has a tiny penalty (probably negligible, but maybe not on some old or under-powered hardware).

If GC is a concern and you want to throw exceptions for reasons of flow control but aren't interested in the details of the exception, other than its type, you can *reuse* exception objects. Create them once as constants and then throw them whenever you want.

But having said all this, I would wait until you know you have a performance problem and then profile to work out how to resolve it. Often it's not the things you think it will be.

Comment: For future reference, the reuse of exceptions is interesting -- thanks.